# MATLAB, recover a signal that has a cosinusoidal interference and that has been AM modulated

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I have this `wav` signal to which has been added a cosinusoidal interference `A cos(2 * Pi * f0 * n * Tc + Phase)` and it has been AM modulated at the same `f0` frequency. `Tc` is the sampling period.

I have the filter coefficients of two filters:

1) notch filter;

2) a low pass filter;

First step:

I calculated the fft of the input signal and it has a big peak at 7500 Hz, which is my `f0` then.

filter 1 is centered at `16KHz`, so I need to shift it such that it is centered at `7500 Hz`. To do so I used the fact that: `exp(j * w0 * n)x(n) -> X(j(w-w0))`. Therefore I multiplied the filter coefficients by `exp(j * 2 * Pi * 8500 * n)`.

I filtered the input with `filtfilt` function

I demodulated the signal by multiplying the output of `filtfilt` by `cos(2 * pi * n * f0 * Tc)`

I filtered the last signal with the low pass filter

Result: the output is still distorted! Where is my mistake?

Comment: What about moving this question to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I belive it should be `exp(j * 2 * Pi * 8500/Fs * n)` where `Fs` is the sampling frequency (or `exp(j * 2 * Pi * 8500 * n * Tc)` if you wish).

Comment: And [this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23585/matlab-recover-a-signal-that-has-a-cosinusoidal-interference-and-that-has-been) is the equivalent post on dsp.stackexchange.com ...